# why skip [Should privilege separation be used? ]

Tags: cygwin

My case:
$ ssh-host-config

*** Info: Generating missing SSH host keys
yse
*** Query: Overwrite existing /etc/ssh_config file? (yes/no) yes

*** Info: Creating default /etc/ssh_config file

*** Query: Overwrite existing /etc/sshd_config file? (yes/no) yes

*** Info: Creating default /etc/sshd_config file

*** Info: StrictModes is set to 'yes' by default.

*** Info: This is the recommended setting, but it requires that the POSIX

*** Info: permissions of the user's home directory, the user's .ssh

*** Info: directory, and the user's ssh key files are tight so that

*** Info: only the user has write permissions.

*** Info: On the other hand, StrictModes don't work well with default

*** Info: Windows permissions of a home directory mounted with the

*** Info: 'noacl' option, and they don't work at all if the home

*** Info: directory is on a FAT or FAT32 partition.

*** Query: Should StrictModes be used? (yes/no) no

*** Info: Updating /etc/sshd_config file

*** Info: Sshd service is already installed.

*** Info: Host configuration finished. Have fun!

It skip Should privilege separation be used?

i can't create cyg_server & sshd

please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of ssh-host-config no longer prompt for enabling privilege separation. It is enabled by default.